# Image is not retrieved correctly

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to capture an image and use it as a gray level image.

I have the following code:

```
CvCapture *p = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
cvSetCaptureProperty(p, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1024);
cvSetCaptureProperty(p, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1024);
IplImage* frame;
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    frame = cvQueryFrame(p);
}
cvSaveImage("test.jpg", frame);

Mat r = imread("test.jpg", 1);
Mat inputImage;
cvtColor(r, inputImage, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

In my code `frame` is an RGB image (three dimensions). when I read the saved image with r it has two channels.

I have two questions:

1. why this happens?
2. how can I have one dimensional image which is gray level?

Comment: "how can I have one dimensional image" - You mean a 1 pixel line?

Comment: actually I meant RGB has three pages. a gray level image has one page

Comment: Huh? Pages?? There are no pages. May I recommend to get comfortable with the commonly used phrases? That will also help you to find resources on your own, instead of asking unclear questions.

Comment: I meant one dimensional matrix. (one dimensional was the commonly used phrase as I used in the question). The code can be run in both C and C++.

Comment: @Olaf also one dimensional gray image just have gray level values and there are not three panes ( R, G, B)

Comment: @media: Why are you using Mat as well as IplImage. Second, confirm the value of "img->nChannels".

Comment: @saurabheights because I needed to capture frame

Comment: @media : Please see this: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

Comment: @saurabheights Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: You should check which camera/hardware you are using? Also, confirm if frame has 2 channels by running:

```
 cout << img->nChannels << endl;
```

For second part:

To read image as gray channel, change:

```
Mat r = imread("test.jpg", 1);
```

to

```
Mat r = imread("test.jpg", 0);
```

See this: [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread)